# What are the version number and identification names for each Falcon 9-r boosters?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-9, recovery

I would like to track the all the Falcon 9-r boosters that are landing or are attempting to land.

I know that the third booster which landed successfully is the F9-0024-S1 but I don't know the version.

Where can I find this information for the previous ones and all future flights as they append?

Comment: The JCSAT-14 mission was the first time I've seen a serial number published. SpaceX have a habit of not giving exact specifications. Even names are kept vague ("Full thrust" instead of v1.2) so I doubt we'll see an official list.

Comment: Some people try to trace the core numbers very precisely - https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/wiki/cores

Comment: @jkavalik I like that one. Can you put it as an answer?

Comment: Well, I did not create any part of it so would not want to take any credit. And it would be a link-only answer too.

Answer (score 4):

[Space Launch Report](http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/falcon9ft.html) keeps a list of serial numbers and versions.

Answer (score 1):

The first to land was the Orbcomm OG2 mission, Dec 21, 2015 which was a F9 1.1 Full Thrust model. It landed at LZ-1 in Florida.

The last F9 1.1 (non-Full thrust version) carried the Jason-3 mission to orbit (Jan 17, 2016), landed on the JRTI barge in the Pacific, but one of the four legs did not lock, so it fell over and expoded.

SES-9 on Mar 4, 2016 failed by running out of fuel, also a F.9 1.1 Full Thrust.

Apr 8, 2016 the CRS-8 mission landed on the OCISLY ASDS a F9 1.1 Full Thrust. F9-023

May 6, 2016 the JCSat-14 mission landed on OCISLY ASDS and was a F91.1 Full Thrust.

There is a good Reddit page that is [tracking Falcon 9 missions](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/wiki/cores) with the info you want.

Wikipedia has a [tracking page of Falcon 9 Missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches) as well.

Someone is generating a PNG from a data file trying to capture all the flight info and I will insert the latest version as of this writing.  I have yet to find a dynamic link to an updated copy alas.

[image: Infographic of SpaceX launches]